# Can I use a noun with a posessive determiner as adjunct?

Tags: grammaticality, determiners, adjuncts

For example: "Your level English" (Your level = adjunct)? Does it have the same meaning as "English of your level"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you'd need to hyphenate, like this: *your-level English*. This would arguably be understood by most native speakers to mean *English of your level*. But I doubt any native speaker would actually use such a construction under normal circumstances; it's just not natural. It is true that there are similar constructions that **are** fully idiomatic, such as [*higher-level math*](https://books.google.com/books?id=x8MeIOYD7SoC&lpg=PA120&dq=%22higher%20level%20math%22&pg=PA120#v=onepage&q=%22higher%20level%20math%22&f=false), [*next-level advice*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NhoyDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT72&dq=%22next%20level%20advice%22&pg=PT73#v=onepage&q=%22next%20level%20advice%22&f=false), etc. But is just a fact of life that *your* normally can't enter into such constructions.

[CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) would refer to both *higher-level* and *next-level* as an **attributive modifier** realized by a **nominal.** The *your-level* modifier would be a **nonce formation** similar to *a no-frills airline* and *an all-or-nothing approach*. *Nonce* here means that 'forms of these types are not 
systematically admissible in this construction' (CGEL, p. 444). In these cases, the obstacle is that they contain determiners (genitives like *your* function as determiners), and determiners are not systematically admisible as constituents of attributive modifiers. They are only admissible as particular nonce formations—sometimes. Not in your case, however. I don't know a deep reason why that is; we just don't normally use *your* (or other possessive pronouns such as *my, his, her, our,* and *their*) in such constructions, and unfortunately that's all I can say about it.

Comment: This post would be twice as good, imo, without the last clause

Answer (score 0):

Level can refer to status or an even, flat surface/temperament. It fits after English not before in your context. 'What is your English level?' Usually, a person would leave the word unspoken, as in 'How's your English?'

Because of its double meaning a person can also complain about unfairness in not finding a level playing field for all. If they raise their voice, you should tell them to keep their tone level, keep a level tone or level their tone.

Helpful?

Comment: The OP wonders when and if it is permissible to replace certain *of your* + N phrases by pre-head modifiers, like this: *people of your background* -> * *your background people*, *country of your origin* -> * *your origin country*, etc. (Answer: generally, that replacement would not result in acceptable constructions.)